# Vue.js problem with importing class from another .js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs, babel-loader

I am new to Vue and already ran into an issue that I can't solve.

I want to import a class from another .js file, where I will store my Axios requests. I have created a *restDataFile.js* file in my *src* folder:

```
import Axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = "my-api-address";

export default class {    
    async foo() {
        await (Axios.get(baseUrl));
    }
}
```

I wanted to import this class to another file (in my case it's my Vuex store file in my *store/index.js* file):

```
import RestDataSource from "./restDataSource";
```

Once I run build I get an error like this:
[Failed to compile with 1 errors Error in ./src/restDataSource.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): TypeError: _core.types.isBigIntLiteral is not a function (...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GQWr.png)

Import works fine if I do not export a class, so for example it works if I modify my *restDataSource.js* file to export:

```
export default {
   foo() { ... }
}
```

Is it an issue with babel configuration or something? Can't find any solution to this error on the web.

Comment: Sounds like you solved your own problem.  Why are you trying to export a class instead of just exporting a function, or even multiple functions?  If you really need a class, you seem to be missing a class name, so try adding one i.e. ```export default class MyClass```.

Comment: I tried that as well, but with the same effect. This however does not answer my question. Why can't I import a class? Of course, I can use function instead, but I would like to understand why the above isn't working.

Comment: Also, as stated below, I did try to use the named class, same effect.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the import. There's something wrong with what you're trying to import. Could you please provide a [mcve] (using codesandbox.io or similar)? Without one, your chances of getting any help are close to `null`, as there's no way to get eyes on the error (trace it back to source). Since the error seems to come from some dependency (which I'm guessing comes from some package), adding `skipLibCheck: true` to your `tsconfig.json` might help. This has a lot more to do with Typescript and Babel than it has to do with Vue, btw.